# ExpandedListView: how to expandGroup or get correct groupPosition with List<Class>

Tags: android, list, object, kotlin, expandablelistview

Before this problem i could expand groups.
Group and child collection was:

```
val header: MutableList<String> = ArrayList()
var productList : MutableList<String> = mutableListOf()
val body: MutableList<MutableList<String>> = mutableListOf()
```

After that I needed to add more data to my header and childs (productList). So i created two model classes:

```
data class Cell (var barcode: String = "", var name: String = "")

data class Product(
    var barcode: String = "",
    var id: String = "",
    var name: String = "",
    var time: String = "",
    var date: String = "",
    var weight: Int = 0
)
```

And changed my collections in Activity to:

```
var header: MutableList<Cell> = mutableListOf()
var productList : MutableList<Product> = mutableListOf()
val body: MutableList<MutableList<Product>> = mutableListOf()
```

My adapter is:

```
class ExpandableListAdapter(var context : Context, var expandableListView: ExpandableListView, var header : MutableList<Cell>, var body: MutableList<MutableList<Product>>) :
    BaseExpandableListAdapter() {

    override fun getGroup(groupPosition: Int): String {
        return header[groupPosition].toString()
    }

    override fun isChildSelectable(groupPosition: Int, childPosition: Int): Boolean {
        return true
    }

    override fun hasStableIds(): Boolean {
        return false
    }

    override fun getGroupView(
        groupPosition: Int,
        isExpanded: Boolean,
        convertView: View?,
        parent: ViewGroup?
    ): View? {
        var convertView = convertView
        if(convertView == null){
            val inflater = context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_group, null)
        }
        val title = convertView?.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textGroupCode)
        title?.text = getGroup(groupPosition)
        val det = header.get(groupPosition)
        title?.setText(det.name.toString())

        title?.setOnClickListener {
            if (expandableListView.isGroupExpanded(groupPosition))
                expandableListView.collapseGroup(groupPosition)
            else
                expandableListView.expandGroup(groupPosition)
            Toast.makeText(context, getGroup(groupPosition).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
        return convertView
    }

    override fun getChildrenCount(groupPosition: Int): Int {
        return body[groupPosition].size
        //return header.get(groupPosition).getChildList().size()
    }

    override fun getChild(groupPosition: Int, childPosition: Int): String {
        return body[groupPosition][childPosition].toString()
        //return header.get(groupPosition).get(childPosition)
    }

    override fun getGroupId(groupPosition: Int): Long {
        return groupPosition.toLong()
    }

    override fun getChildView(
        groupPosition: Int,
        childPosition: Int,
        isLastChild: Boolean,
        convertView: View?,
        parent: ViewGroup?
    ): View? {
        var convertView = convertView
        if(convertView == null){
            val inflater = context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_child, null)
        }
        val title = convertView?.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textChildId)
        title?.text = getChild(groupPosition, childPosition)
        val name = convertView?.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textChildName)
        val date = convertView?.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textChildDate)
        val time = convertView?.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textChildTime)
        val weight = convertView?.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textChildWeight)

        val det = body.get(groupPosition).get(childPosition)
        title?.setText(det.id.toString())
        name?.setText(det.name.toString())
        date?.setText(det.date.toString())
        time?.setText(det.time.toString())
        weight?.setText(det.weight.toString())

        title?.setOnClickListener {
            Toast.makeText(context, getChild(groupPosition, childPosition), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
        return convertView
    }

    override fun getChildId(groupPosition: Int, childPosition: Int): Long {
        return childPosition.toLong()
    }

    override fun getGroupCount(): Int {
        return header.size
    }
}
```

Now when i try to expand/click on my group or child, i get class with his all field values. I dont get position of element. How to fix this? How to work with List of class and get correct position???

Answer (score 0):

Please try this one, i have print group position, child position and handle expend event.

```
     class ExpendNewListAdapter(
               var mContext: Context,
                       var  mListDataHeader: List<String>?,
                       var mListDataChild: HashMap<String, List<EventsItem>?>?) : BaseExpandableListAdapter() {
override fun getChild(groupPosition: Int, childPosititon: Int): Any {
    return this.mListDataChild?.get(this.mListDataHeader?.get(groupPosition))!!.get(childPosititon)
}

override fun getChildId(groupPosition: Int, childPosition: Int): Long {
    return childPosition.toLong()
}

override fun getChildView(groupPosition: Int, childPosition: Int,
                          isLastChild: Boolean, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup): View {


    val events = getChild(groupPosition, childPosition) as EventsItem

    val infalInflater = this.mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
      val  childView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_expandable, null)

    val txtListEventName = childView
            .findViewById<View>(R.id.text_event_name) as TextView

    Log.e("child Position",childPosition.toString())

    return childView
}

override fun getChildrenCount(groupPosition: Int): Int {
    return this.mListDataChild?.get(this.mListDataHeader?.get(groupPosition))?.size ?:0
}

override fun getGroup(groupPosition: Int): String? {
    return this.mListDataHeader?.get(groupPosition)
}

override fun getGroupCount(): Int {
    return this.mListDataHeader?.size?:0
}

override fun getGroupId(groupPosition: Int): Long {
    return groupPosition.toLong()
}

override fun getGroupView(groupPosition: Int, isExpanded: Boolean,
                          convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup): View {
    val infalInflater = this.mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
     val headerView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.expend_list_layout, null)

    val innerLayout = headerView
            .findViewById<View>(R.id.layout_inner) as ConstraintLayout


    val viewBottom = headerView
            .findViewById<View>(R.id.view_botttom_parent) as View
    Log.e("group Position",groupPosition.toString())
        if(isExpanded ) {
            innerLayout.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.button_green))
            viewBottom.visibility = View.GONE
        }
        else
        {
            innerLayout.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext,R.color.button_blue))
            viewBottom.visibility=View.VISIBLE
        }



    return headerView
}

override fun hasStableIds(): Boolean {
    return false
}

override fun isChildSelectable(groupPosition: Int, childPosition: Int): Boolean {
    return true
}
```

}

Comment: Can you paste your collections from Activity?

Comment: Please check my second answer

Answer (score 0):

In my case i have set all events month wise, where group items are month and child  items are all events which are getting from my response.you can change as per your requirement.

```
 if (dataList != null && dataList.size > 0) {
        text_empty.visibility = View.GONE


        mListDataHeader = ArrayList()
        mListDataChild = HashMap()

        // Adding the header of parent.because month are common for each year then put static data
        mListDataHeader?.add(getString(R.string.january))
        mListDataHeader?.add(getString(R.string.feburary))
        mListDataHeader?.add(getString(R.string.march))
        mListDataHeader?.add(getString(R.string.april))
        mListDataHeader?.add(getString(R.string.may))
        mListDataHeader?.add(getString(R.string.june))
        mListDataHeader?.add(getString(R.string.july))
        mListDataHeader?.add(getString(R.string.august))
        mListDataHeader?.add(getString(R.string.sep))
        mListDataHeader?.add(getString(R.string.oct))
        mListDataHeader?.add(getString(R.string.nov))
        mListDataHeader?.add(getString(R.string.dec))

        mIsRequestForAccess?.let {
            if (!it) {
                mListDataHeader?.add("")                 /* these blank item to create space in bottom for
                                                 scrolling the list up to request for access view*/
                mListDataHeader?.add("")
            }
        }

        /* In this List First we are check the list of event item is empty or not
         * if it is empty then we add a blank item for "No Event Found".if  the list is not blank then
          * we check start and end date are common or not if it is comman then we create a new list and add a event in this list
          * and if the date are not common then we get all dates between start and end date..and create a different events
          * of those dates..(events name and title are common between start and end date so we change only start date of
          *  all event which are belong from those dates)..we show the child events for base on start dates.so we change only start date*/
        for (item in dataList.indices) {
            mListDataChild?.let {

                if (dataList[item]?.events?.size == 0) {
                    var list: List<EventsItem>? = null
                    list = ArrayList()
                    val events = EventsItem(null, null, null, getString(R.string.not_events_found), null)
                    list.add(events)
                    it.put(mListDataHeader!!.get(item), list)
                } else {
                    var newList: List<EventsItem>? = null
                    newList = ArrayList()
                    val events = dataList[item]?.events as List<EventsItem>?

                    val monthDate=dataList[item]?.date
                    events?.let {

                        for (i in it.indices) {
                            val event = it[i]
                            val startTime = event.startDate
                            val endTime = event.endDate
                            val startDate=Utils.getFormatedTimeFromUtc(startTime,getString(R.string.date_format_data))
                            val endDate=Utils.getFormatedTimeFromUtc(endTime,getString(R.string.date_format_data))
                            val colors = event.color
                            val description = event.description
                            val title = event.title
                            if (startDate.equals(endDate)) {
                                newList.add(event)
                            } else {
                                /* get all dates between start and end date*/
                                var startnewDate: String? = null
                                val mLists = Utils.getDates(startDate, endDate, activity)
                                val newFormate = SimpleDateFormat(getString(R.string.date_format_data), Locale.getDefault())
                                val format = SimpleDateFormat(getString(R.string.date_month_formats), Locale.getDefault())
                                var mDateStart: Date? = null

                                try {

                                    mDateStart = newFormate.parse(startDate)
                                    startnewDate = format.format(mDateStart)
                                } catch (e: ParseException) {
                                    e.printStackTrace()
                                }
                                mLists.let {
                                    for (data in it.indices) {

                                        val dateFormat = SimpleDateFormat(getString(R.string.date_format_data), Locale.getDefault())
                                        val datenew = format.format(it[data])
                                        if (datenew == monthDate) {

                                            val newData = dateFormat.format(it[data])
                                            val newEvent = EventsItem(endDate, colors, description, title, newData)
                                            newList.add(newEvent)
                                        }

                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }

                    }

                    val sortedList = newList.sortedWith(compareBy({ it.startDate }))
                    it[mListDataHeader!!.get(item)] = sortedList as List<EventsItem>?
                }
            }
            setData()
        }
    } else {
        text_empty.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    }
```